# How to join two Style[]d strings

Tags: string-manipulation

Does anyone know whether it is possible to combine\join two styled strings?

That is, while the following code works fine:

```
omega = "text";
omega<>omega
```

when I try to join my omegas into one string but having different colors like this

```
Style[omega,Lighter[Blue,.1]]<>Style[omega,Darker[LightBlue,.1]]
```

mma returns this error:

> `StringJoin::string: String expected at position 1`

It's clear to me that the objects I'm trying to join have head `Style` not `String`, but may be there is a way to produce a string that has its parts painted in different colors?

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7732/121

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Use `Row` to join them:

```
Omega = "text";
joined = Row[{Style[Omega, Lighter[Blue, .1]], Style[Omega, Darker[LightBlue, .1]]}];
Print[joined]
```

Comment: Though this is a quick fix for most of the cases, whenever the result is expected to be a `String`, I prefer WReach's solution. Not to mention that `Row` breaks lines differently than how the FE prints strings.

Comment: Hi István, I agree.  Since I read WReach's solution I have found it very useful.

Answer (score 50):

Given two styled items:

```
omega = "text"

items = { Style[omega,Lighter[Blue,.1]], Style[omega,Darker[LightBlue,.1]] }
```

We can produce a single string with both stylings if we convert each item into a `StandardForm` string prior to joining them:

```
Apply[StringJoin, ToString[#, StandardForm] & /@ items]
```

The following screenshot shows the results:

[image: styled concatenation session]

Comment: Nice.  Also `Row@items ~ToString~ StandardForm` though the format is not as clean.

Answer (score 13):

If you evaluate or print the following string you get what you want:

```
"\!\(\*StyleBox[\"text\",FontColor->RGBColor[1, 0, 0]]\) \!\(\*StyleBox[\"text\",FontColor->RGBColor[0, 0, 1]]\)"
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is a single string and it contains color information for different substrings.

```
Do[Print@"\!\(\*StyleBox[\"text\",FontColor->RGBColor[1, 0, 0]]\) \!\(\*StyleBox[\"text\",FontColor->RGBColor[0, 0, 1]]\)", {5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score -3):

```
**Bold and underline a String and return String
  If you like, you can mix and match any style combo by
  simply adding or subtracting lines the following Module**

toEm[str_  ] := Module[{s1,s2},
    s1 = ToString[Style[str, Bold] , StandardForm];
    s2 = ToString[Style[s1, Underlined] , StandardForm]
]
```

Comment: The problem was to join two strings, each of which has been styled with `Style[]`, not to apply two styles to one string.  See @WReach's answer, for instance.  -- BTW, you can combine your two steps into one: `ToString[Style[str, Bold, Underlined], StandardForm]`

Answer (score -3):

Following the details from the Mathematica documentation page for [`Style`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Style.html) especially the examples in the section Options:

```
Style[omega, Lighter[Blue, .1]] Style[omega, Darker[LightBlue, .1]]
```

[image: output for the two Style boxes in one input separated by a single blanc]

This follows the methodology offered in Options>SingleLetterItalics:
Style[T, SingleLetterItalics -> False] + Sin[x y] // TraditionalForm
all three output boxes are present each after eachother:
sin(x y)+T

sin(x y)

"+"

T

in one output.

The gray x is allowed too.

This works in
Print[Style[omega, Lighter[Blue, .1]] Style[omega,
Darker[LightBlue, .1]]]
[image: output]

To make Yourself an impression compare:

```
Column[Options[Row]]
```

to
Column[Options[Style]]

```
Options[Style] // Length
```

(*190*)
Options[Row] // Length
(*15*)

One `Style` for one expression with many, up to 190 options.

Mathematica has too the built-in `StyleBox`. That is in need for the built-in `DisplayForm` to be shown as `Style` in the output line. And for this there is the built-in `AdjustmentBox`. This built-in together with `RowBox` allow wide range formattings of the combination of `Style` for strings displayed in the output line. The authors of the Mathematica documentation cut the length of the input already at this depth of nesting.

```
RowBox[Table[
   AdjustmentBox[Style["x", RGBColor[0.8 - b, 0.2 - b, 0.5 - b]], 
    BoxBaselineShift -> b], {b, -.2, .2, .2}]] // DisplayForm
```

[image]

[Have fun with layout and color.](http://%3Cimg%20src=%22http://vg09.met.vgwort.de/na/d3f43108e5714c4fb80bcf73373ff7b7%22%20width=%221%22%20height=%221%22%20alt=%22%3E)