# How to highlight a string pattern?

Tags: string-manipulation

This is an example in the help pages ([Working with patterns: Highlight Patterns](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/WorkingWithStringPatterns.html)):

```
    SeedRandom[12345];
    dna=StringJoin[Table[{"a","c","t"}[[RandomInteger[{1,3}]]],{50}]]

    StringReplace[dna,x:("a"~~_~~"a"):>"\!\(\*StyleBox[\""<>x<>"\",
FontColor->RGBColor[1,0,0],FontSize->18,FontWeight->\"Bold\"]\)"]
```

> ```
> "\!\(\*StyleBox[\"aca\",\n    FontColor->RGBColor[1,FontWeight->\"Bold\"]\)atccttttattactcccacccatcccatc\!\(\*StyleBox[\"ata\",\n    FontColor->RGBColor[1,0,0],FontSize->18,FontWeight->\"Bold\"]\)ctatcttctct\!\(\*StyleBox[\"ata\",\n    FontColor->RGBColor[1,0,0],FontSize->18,FontWeight->\"Bold\"]\)t"
> ```
>
> [image: screen grab]

## How to highlight the black part of the DNA with a pattern# (any professional name)?

**Method 1: not perfect,  some problem see appendix I**

```
rules=MapThread[RuleDelayed,{StringSplit[dna,x:("ag"~~_~~_~~"t"~~_~~"ca")],Style[#,Red]&/@StringSplit[dna,x:("ag"~~_~~_~~"t"~~_~~"ca")]}];
StringReplace[dna,rules]
```

> ```
> acttaagctttcgggtgagtgtactgcccactcctagctttcctttagttcttagacgagctggcgcgtagatggctacgtgacttgaatgcattagtgtctagatgcattatggaaccattccaatcgtctcggagggctagtgctgccatcttggttatgtggtatcgtgatttgaatcagtccagcgctataaagtcttcgctgtt~~aggctgca~~ggagccgagggcatcggacgtacaaaatgcgggggtagactgacgaccgcagaggccacatacgacaggccgccggcgtgcgactagatagccgcgagtggggttggctaagcacatcga~~agtgtaca~~gaaaacccctaccccatgagtcgtgcagacgcctccagaaaccagg~~agtttaca~~gcaggacctgagaactaatgttaatgctccatcacctctgcatgcctatccattaagcaaggcacactcagcccctaaaagcgagcggctccccaggagaa
> ```

[image]

**[update1]**
sub question 1: How to remove the StringExpression (~~) to improve it? thanks for rm and Silva's tips, [this is solved].

**[unsolved-main problem]**sub Question 2: How to achieve the effect in a better way without appendix I's problem? my first thought is to use *Except*,but failed

Following are the CellPrint effects:

```
 CellPrint@TextCell[Row[List@@StringReplace[dna,rules],""],"Text"]
```

> ```
> "acttaagctttcgggtgagtgtactgcccactcctagctttcctttagttcttagacgagctggcgcgtagatggctacgtgacttgaatgcattagtgtctagatgcattatggaaccattccaatcgtctcggagggctagtgctgccatcttggttatgtggtatcgtgatttgaatcagtccagcgctataaagtcttcgctgtt""aggctgca""ggagccgagggcatcggacgtacaaaatgcgggggtagactgacgaccgcagaggccacatacgacaggccgccggcgtgcgactagatagccgcgagtggggttggctaagcacatcga""agtgtaca""gaaaacccctaccccatgagtcgtgcagacgcctccagaaaccagg""agtttaca""gcaggacctgagaactaatgttaatgctccatcacctctgcatgcctatccattaagcaaggcacactcagcccctaaaagcgagcggctccccaggagaa"
> ```

## Appendix I

When I'm trying golden's suggest to shorten my example, @m_goldberg

> ```
>    SeedRandom[12345];
>     dna = StringJoin[Table[{"a", "c", "t"}[[RandomInteger[{1, 3}]]], {50}]]
>     rules=MapThread[RuleDelayed,{StringSplit[dna,x:("a"~~_~~"a")],Style[#,Red]    &/@StringSplit[dna,x:("a"~~_~~"a")]}];
>     StringReplace[dna,rules]
> ```

[image]

Comment: In general, you'd be better off using `Row` to join styled strings, and this is answered in http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10990/5. Also see WReach's answer on converting to `StandardForm` and then using `StringJoin`

Comment: Try replacing your `Style[#, Red]&` with `ToString[Style[#, Red], StandardForm]&` in the `rules`.

Comment: Please use shorter strings in your examples. There is no need to use a string of 500 characters. You could surely produce an example with 100 characters or less.

Comment: @rm -rf thanks for tips, I see some examples in Help Pages use Row To remove StringExpression~~ ,so I tried that. ,

Comment: @Silvia it works, thanks

Comment: @m_goldberg some problem show up when I tried shorten the example in method 1

Comment: Ok, since Silvia's comment solved your problem and that is exactly one of the solutions in the linked post (which is very similar to this one), I'm marking it a duplicate. Please let me know if this is not the case (and why)

Comment: @rm-rf how do you think about appendix I's problem, I think to acieve method 1's effect is the main problem of this post.