# Typing custom plotlegend

Tags: legending

I have the following ListStepPlot:

```
ListStepPlot[{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, \
-1, -1}, LabelStyle -> 
Directive[FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", Plain, FontSize -> 11], 
PlotLegends -> {Subscript[Style["t", Bold], Style[p, Plain]] -> 
Style["F", Bold] <> "\[Congruent]" <> Style["I", Bold]}, 
PlotRange -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {"\!\(\*
StyleBox[SubscriptBox[
StyleBox[\"e\",\nFontWeight->\"Plain\"], \"i\"],\nFontWeight->\"Plain\
\"]\)", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(t\), \(i\)]\)"}]
```

My question is: How can I format the plot legend such that "t" is bold, p is the subscript of "t", and also "F" and "I" are bold?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join two Style\[\]d strings](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10990/how-to-join-two-styled-strings)

Comment: Also, you currently only have a single list of numbers which means only one legend (the blue one) will be displayed. If you want two legends to display, you should have something like `ListStepPlot[{{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, ...}, list2},...]`.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use [`Row`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row.html) for your plot legend. Like so:

```
ListStepPlot[ConstantArray[1, 45]~ Join~ ConstantArray[-1, 16], 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", FontSize -> 11],
 PlotLegends ->
   Style[Row[{Subscript["t", Style[p, Plain]], "→", "F", "≡", "I"}], Bold, "TR"],
   PlotRange -> Automatic,
   AxesLabel -> {Subscript[e, i], Subscript[t, i]}]
```

[image: plot]