# How to strip all formatting from a string and convert it to plain text?

Tags: string-manipulation, formatting, style

The documentation on [`String`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/String.html) states:

[image: Strings preserve internal formatting]

But if I try to perform some manipulations on this string, for example, take 2 words from the left, I get some shards of internal representation instead (which is understandable):

```
(* In[2]:= *) StringTake[%1, 8]
(* Out[2]= "\!\(\*\nStyl" *)
```

*Question:* Is it possible to write a function which strips all formatting (colors, fonts, style, size, etc) from a string and returns just a plain text?

Comment: Somewhat related: [(7732)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7732/121), [(10990)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10990/121)

Comment: Thanks for the Accept, but I recommend all users wait 24-hours to let everyone have a chance to answer.  You may like another answer more if you give it a chance to happen.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For most strings you can use simply:

```
ToString[string]
```

Or more rigorously:

```
ToString[string, OutputForm]
```

Observe:

[image]

---

If your styled string includes two dimensional formatting that you do not wish to change you will find `OutputForm` unacceptable.  Of course the 2D formatting itself will mean that the string cannot be in a "plain" form, but we can still strip styling directives such as size, slant, and color.  Here is a rather baroque way to deal with that.  I will use the gloriously-named `UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket` [described here by John Fultz](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13371/121).  I will then convert these Boxes back into a string and strip a remnant `TagBox` (using `StringTake`) to produce the cleanest string possible.

```
parseString[s_String, prep : (True | False) : True] := 
  FrontEndExecute @ FrontEnd`UndocumentedTestFEParserPacket[s, prep]

cleanString[s_String] :=
  ToString[DisplayForm@parseString[s, True][[1, 1]], StandardForm] //
    "\!" <> StringTake[#, {11, -16}] &
```

Observe:

[image]

Comment: Could this be changed to filter out all boxes, like SuperscriptBox and SubscriptBox?