# How to remove style from a styled number?

Tags: style, head

For example, I have a number with style like so:
`Style[1, Red, 20]`

How do I remove its style, so it returns to its inner value `1`? Is there a function that can allow me to remove the head "Style"?

Comment: Look at [`First`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/First.html).

Comment: Helpful, but further question is if it's a mixed number and styled number.. Say {1,Style[2,Red],3,Style[4,Red]}

Comment: Somewhat related: [(29817)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/29817/121)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without greater context I recommend a simple [`ReplaceAll`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReplaceAll.html) operation, to work on all appearances of `Style` at any level.

```
{1, Style[2, Red], 3, Style[4, Red]} /. Style[x_, ___] :> x
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 3, 4}
> ```

If you want to strip `Style` from *only* numbers then you could use something like:

```
/. Style[x_?NumberQ, ___] :> x
```

Answer (score 5):

This should work (untested):

```
removeStyle[expr_Style] := removeStyle@First[expr]
removeStyle[expr_] := expr
```

---

The best solution would be to avoid storing styled numbers in the first place, if you intend to compute with them. Only style them at the last minute before displaying them, but do not store the styled version if you can avoid it.

Comment: +1 for the good advice

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps something like (not extensively tested)?

```
stripStyle = ToExpression@*StripBoxes@*ToBoxes
```

which strips general non-semantic elements from an expression

```
{1, Style[2, Red], 3, Style[4, Red], Framed[6]} // stripStyle
(* {1, 2, 3, 4, 6} *)
```

Comment: Nice method. One caveat: [(216544)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/216544/121)

Comment: Good comment! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Format | Clear Formatting` menu item for this. Highlight the offending symbols, and use the menu item. There should also be a keyboard shortcut, on MacOS it is <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Delete</kbd>.