# Highlighting pattern strings in a large text

Tags: performance-tuning, pattern-matching, string-manipulation, text, style

I would like to apply `Style` to strings that are matched, for example, with one or more specified patterns or regular expressions, a string or a list of both, whatever.

I've already written a function that works fine with small text samples, but it is slow and it has problems to export ( a RTF ) correctly, cause a formatting problem.

```
Highlight[pattern_, style_] := 
 s_String :> (Row[{##}] & @@ 
    StringReplace[s, t : pattern :> style[t], IgnoreCase -> False])
```

So for example try it with a short text:

```
txt = Import["http://www.google.com"] // 
   StringReplace[#, {"\t", "\r\n", "\n"} -> ""] &;

txt /. Highlight[RegularExpression["[A-Z][a-z]+"], Style[#, Blue] &]
```

The output looks like:

[image: string replace with styles]

My scenario:

- Issue 1: the input text is a long string, i.e ~500KB so far.
- Issue 2: I want to be able send a list of patterns without drastically impacting the runtime or the normal behavior of the kernel. (Right now when I render more than one pattern in a large text sample with the current code, the kernel crashes).
- Issue 3: It seems that *the programming using these pattern* replaces are so slow.

Is there a better way to run this pattern matching, or a more efficient approach to find and highlight specific text?

**UPDATE:**
Sharing some kind of my input based on the comments:

```
txt = ExampleData[{"Text", "AeneidEnglish"}];
somewords = 
  DictionaryLookup[RegularExpression[".*tion"]] // Take[#, 200] &;

In[536]:= AbsoluteTiming[
 txt /. Highlight[somewords, Style[#, Blue] &];]

Out[536]= {7.84513, Null}
```

Based on a list of words, and RegularExpression for the pattern argument, it seems to be the method is doing the necessary work, so far. 
Apparently this method is the fastest.

Comment: Seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7008)?

Comment: So I tried using your `Highlight` rule on `ExampleData[{"Text", AeneidEnglish"}]`, which is about 600 kB, and it was pretty fast (~50 ms). However, trying to export the result to RTF took quite a while. Is the issue with the export step?

Comment: @J.M. Yes, before asking my function is almost the same like MrWizard's

Comment: Yes, my problem here @Pillsy it seems to be the export and in addition if I send a list big enough of strings

Comment: @d555 Do you really need RTF, or would other formats (like, say, HTML) work for you?

Comment: @Pillsy it could be other but it must to a format valid tonopen with MS Office word. You know, it is popular.

Comment: @d555  HTML might be worth a try, then, since Word can import that.

Comment: When I try your second line (`txt /. `...), I get an error:  "\!\({Highlight[RegularExpression[\"[A-Z][a-z]+\"], Style[#1, Blue] \
&]}\) is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch \
table, and so cannot be used for replacing. "  I also don't see how `Highlight[`...`]` can be a replacement rule.  Is there a typo'?

Comment: @Pillsy I tried with HTML and its pretty slower than rtf. :(

Comment: @EricTowers for me works

Comment: @d555 could you post some example rules- when I run this with the ExampleData[{"Text", "AeneidEnglish"}] It takes < 5 seconds

Comment: Could you post an example code highlighting issue 2?

Comment: Check the post again, I added a example of mines.

Comment: @ddd You are aware that if you don't reward someone with your bounty, the half of your reputation goes into `/dev/null`. The other half is in this case rewarded to me I guess, because I have to most upvotes. I'm not entirely sure about the rules. Ignoring the outcome of the bounty that you started, because your question was ignored is probably the worst solution.

Comment: I just have doubts with your answer because the style is not a parameter and should i always look for xml of the style that i want to use?

Comment: @d555 Oh, I didn't know that you were having problems making the style a parameter of the function. I intentionally left this out because it makes the core of my idea clearer. You can easily make the style a parameter of the highlighting function. Ah, and I see now that you already asked me this in the comment. I can include this. Btw, you could give the bounty to Peter's answer too! I don't have a problem with that. It's just fake internet points. But you should not simply waste them because you won't get them back. If you are up for a [chat] at some time, we could discuss ....

Comment: your problem further, because I don't know whether you have a working solution now.

Comment: Yes. I could, But each part of your answer is useful to me

Comment: Related: [(7008)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7008/121), [(7732)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7732/121), [(10990)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10990/121), [(13312)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13312/121)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is another way that is on my machine almost 500x faster then your solution. The idea is to look how *Mathematica* represents colored strings and use this directly.

When we colorize an input string by selecting text and using the *Format* menu, we can create something like this

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Now, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> to see the underlying expression.

```
Cell[BoxData["\"\<Hello 
  \!\(\*StyleBox[\"my\",FontColor->RGBColor[1, 0, 0]]\)
  friend\>\""], "Input"]
```

I have put the important part in the second like and you see, it's only an inline style-box that is used.

In your updated question, you used a list of words to highlight and for this task, there is another approach useful:

- we create a function that takes a string and returns the same colorized string when it is in your list of words. Otherwise, it just returns the same string
- we split your input into words and apply this function to each word
- we rebuild all words into a string again which now contains normal text and highlighted words.

For this purpose, I use a `Module` that *on-the-fly* creates local functions that do the highlighting. This is important, because with each call to `highlight` you might want to provide a different list of words to highlight. Therefore, the function `doHighlight` needs to be rebuilt on every call.

Sounds expensive? It is not and the implementation is only a few lines long:

```
highlight[txt_, words_] := Module[{colorize, doHighlight},
  colorize[str_] := "\!\(\*StyleBox[\"" <> str <> 
    "\",FontColor->RGBColor[0, 0, 1]]\)";
  SetAttributes[doHighlight, {Listable}];
  (doHighlight[#] := colorize[#]) & /@ words;
  doHighlight[s_] := s;
  StringRiffle[doHighlight[StringSplit[txt]]]
]
```

Let's test it

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Now let us time this with the same input that Peter Roberge used. His function needed 3.7 seconds on my machine.

```
txt = ExampleData[{"Text", "AeneidEnglish"}];
somewords = DictionaryLookup[RegularExpression["[A-Z][a-z]+"]];

output = highlight[txt, somewords]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.168501, Null} *)
```

And the text is highlighted as expected

[image]

Since you were brave enough to read until the end, let me tell you that there is one significant drawback: *Mathematica* has a bug and does not export colored strings to `rtf` correctly. At least on my machine, the text is not colorized in the final `rtf`.

### Update

In case you really need to replace not a fixed word, but an expression you need to use `StringReplace` because it is possible you match more than one word (maybe a group of words). Therefore, splitting the text into words won't always work.

Nevertheless, the basic idea of my answer stays the same: We don't use `Row` and `Style`, but we inject inline string styles and transform a string into string.

The function itself becomes very easy:

```
highlight2[txt_, patterns_] := 
 StringReplace[txt, str : (Alternatives @@ patterns) :> 
   "\!\(\*StyleBox[\"" <> str <> "\",FontColor->RGBColor[0, 0, 1]]\)"
]
```

Here a short test with different kinds of patterns:

```
highlight2["Hello bear, what are you doing here?", 
  { "b" ~~ LetterCharacter .., 
    _ ~~ "o" ~~ _, 
    RegularExpression["[A-Z][a-z]+"], 
    "re?"
   }]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

### Update to provide custom style

Providing a custom style is possible too. You can just add this as parameter and the only thing you have to do inside the function is to transform this into a string and put it at the right place.

That being said:

```
highlight2[txt_, patterns_] := highlight2[txt, patterns, {Blue}];
highlight2[txt_, patterns_, {style__}] := 
 StringReplace[txt, 
  str : (Alternatives @@ patterns) :> 
   "\!\(\*StyleBox[\"" <> str <> "\"," <> 
    StringRiffle[ToString /@ {style}, ", "]
    <> "]\)"]
```

You can now give a list of style directives as last argument. When you leave them out, then the matching text becomes blue.

```
highlight2["Hello bear, what are you doing here?", {"b" ~~ 
 LetterCharacter .., _ ~~ "o" ~~ _},
 {30, Red, Italic}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for wrote this, of course I read it until the end. But, What if I had to send a particular Style? and not just a List of words, a List of RegularExpression as well? And What you mentioned about colorized on RTF, It know that. It seems works only on Windows, so lame, btw, I have *nix.

Comment: @d555 I'm on Linux too. Please see my update. You can easily handle patterns too. Hope this helps. Btw, have you noticed that e.g. XML does export those colorized text correctly? It seems a *feature* of RTF that this doesn't work.

Comment: @ddd Please see the end of my answer for providing custom style.

Comment: following the first version, that it supposed to be fast dealing with a list a words... How can i avoid the stringsplit, cause the result text string miss the newline characters by example, and they are important for me. Thanks dude

Comment: Note that while for usual words containing only alphabetical characters the construct `"\!\(\*StyleBox[\"" <> str <> "\"` works, in general we have to use `"\!\(\*StyleBox[\"\\\"" <> str <> "\\\"\"` as found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/162777/280).

Answer (score 4):

I really enjoy Mathematica when I can outsource tough algorithmic decisions to their source code- I believe this is the case here.

It appears as if your code is doing something expensive (searching and replacing) many *different* times.

I propose to do it all at once.

Benchmark:

```
txt = ExampleData[{"Text", "AeneidEnglish"}];
somewords = DictionaryLookup[RegularExpression["[A-Z][a-z]+"]];
AbsoluteTiming[txt /. Highlight[somewords, Style[#, Blue] &]][[1]]

82.7385
```

Set up:

```
txt = ExampleData[{"Text", "AeneidEnglish"}];
somewords = DictionaryLookup[RegularExpression["[A-Z][a-z]+"]];
```

Generate your rules:

```
rl = Flatten[# -> Style[#, Blue, Bold]] & /@ somewords;
```

Put rules on Virgil's Epic:

```
a = Row[{##}] & @@ StringReplace[txt , rl];
```

Second benchmark:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
  rl = Flatten[# -> Style[#, Blue, Bold]] & /@ somewords;
  a = Row[{##}] & @@ StringReplace[txt , rl];][[1]]

2.4377
```

Export:

```
Export["a.rtf", a]
```

Comment: Thanks, I really like your idea. So using rules and `StringReplace` I can do it at once. And what do you say about RegularExpression? A list of them? or a mix of strings and regexs? and a custom style?

Comment: Yep- your String / Regex, are under the "Rule" umbrella, so you can mix them (if you want). If you post some examples of the mixed rules we can try them out.

Answer (score 2):

```
SearchAll[sequence_, search_] := Module[{map},  map = Map[# -> 
  "\!\(\*StyleBox[\"" <> # <> "\",FontColor->" <> 
   ToString@RGBColor[RandomReal[], RandomReal[], RandomReal[]] <> 
   "]\)" & , search];
 StringReplace[sequence, map]]


SearchAll["CGACATCACCGATGGGGAAGATCGGGCTCGCCACTTCGGGCTCATGA", {"CGA", "CATG"}] // Style[#, FontSize -> 20] &
```

[image: the output can be seen below]