# How to change the word's color in string

Tags: string-manipulation

The picture I load is my target:

[image]

This is my code in mathematica

```
    StringTemplate["``Ratio is ``,``Ratio is ``,``Ratio is ``,"][
 Sequence @@ 
  Flatten@Transpose[{{Style["red", Red, Bold], 
      Style["green", Green, Bold], Style["blue", Blue, Bold]}, {0.1, 
      0.2, 0.3}}]]
```

But the result is

[image]

What's problem in my code?Can Anybody give some advice?

Comment: Try the option `InsertionFunction -> (ToString[#, TraditionalForm] &)`

Comment: If the expression need not be a string, you could use `Row`.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8956915/mathematica-how-to-have-text-in-multiple-colors

Comment: @ChipHurst that should be an answer.  Perhaps more compact if you use `InsertionFunction -> (ToString[Style@@#, TraditionalForm] &)`, then you can omit the `Style` from each list item.

Comment: @Chip Hurst Thanks very much.

Comment: Related: "[Highlighting pattern strings in a large text](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/95912/280)," also [(7732)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7732/280).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Row@MapThread[
  Row[{Style[#1, ToExpression@#1, Bold], " Ratio is ", #2, #3}] &,
  {{"Red", "Green", "Blue"}, {0.1, 0.2, 0.3}, {", ", ", ", ""}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
TemplateApply[
 StringTemplate["`` Ratio is ``, `` Ratio is ``, `` Ratio is ``"], 
 Flatten[Transpose[{ToString[#, StandardForm] & /@ {Style["Red", Red, 
       Bold], Style["Green", Green, Bold], 
      Style["Blue", Blue, Bold]}, {0.1, 0.2, 0.3}}]]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As per [How to join Styled strings](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11002/363)

```
str = StringJoin[
  ToString[Style["red ", Red], StandardForm],
  "Ratio is 0.1, ",
  ToString[Style["green ", Green], StandardForm],
  "Ratio is 0.2, ",
  ToString[Style["blue ", Blue], StandardForm],
  "Ratio is 0.3"]
```

[image]

```
StringQ[str]
```

> True