# How do I find and highlight the elements of a list that match a specific pattern?

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

I have a list of positive and negative ones {1,1,-1,1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,1,1,1,-1} And I want to find and highlight the subsequence of the lists that have the pattern {...,1,1,___,-1,-1,...}. So ideally my output would be {1,1,-1,**1**,**1**,**-1**,**1**,**-1**,**1**,**-1**,**-1**,1,1,1,-1}.

Comment: related: [95912](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/95912/5478)

Answer (score 6):

```
list = {1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, -1};

SequenceCases[list, {a___, Shortest[b : PatternSequence[1, 1, ___, -1, -1]],  c__} :> 
  Flatten[{a, Style[#, Bold, Red] & /@ {b}, c}]][[1]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Note: the subsequence starting with the first entry also satisfies your pattern, and it can be obtained by removing`Shortest` above or by changing it to `Longest`:

```
SequenceCases[list, {a___, b : PatternSequence[1, 1, ___, -1, -1],  c__} :> 
  Flatten[{a, Style[#, Bold, Red] & /@ {b}, c}]][[1]]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Is there a way to find the first time that pattern occurs? The code is taking a really long time to run with your solution, and I think finding the first occurrence might still give me what I need.

Comment: @xanadu, using the third argument `SequenceCases[list, {a___, b : PatternSequence[1, 1, ___, -1, -1],  c__} :>  
  Flatten[{a, Style[#, Bold, Red] & /@ {b}, c}], n]` gives the first `n` matches.