# What is the problem with the "|" character inside of strings?

Tags: export, string-manipulation, pdf-format, text, style

When the `"|"` character appears inside of a string containing *linear box syntax*, `SyntaxQ` returns `False` and FrontEnd often fails to display the string correctly. Consider:

1. A string with an alphabetical character embedded in linear box syntax, it's OK:

   ```
   "\!\(\*StyleBox[\"a\"]\)" // SyntaxQ
   ```

   > ```
   > True
   > ```
2. When we put the `"|"` character (which is ASCII!), something goes wrong:

   ```
   "\!\(\*StyleBox[\"|\"]\)" // SyntaxQ
   ```

   > ```
   > False
   > ```
3. Well, let us take what *Mathematica* suggests:

   ```
   str = ToString[Style["|"], StandardForm];
   str // SyntaxQ
   str // InputForm
   ```

   > ```
   > True
   >
   > "\!\(\*StyleBox[\"\\\"|\\\"\", Rule[StripOnInput, False]]\)"
   > ```

Now it looks OK, but I wish to have additional `"|"` in the string, so I try:

```
str <> "|" // SyntaxQ
```

> ```
> False
> ```

Again something goes wrong (but why???), while with the alphabetical characters it's OK:

```
str <> "a" // SyntaxQ
```

> ```
> True
> ```

`StringJoin` of `str` with itself is also OK, but I don't wish to blow up my file having every `"|"` character wrapped by the linear syntax. The above is just a minimal working example, of course. Actually I'm constructing a string containing both `Bold` and `Plain` (the default style) symbols `"|"`.

I'm working with large strings and wish to keep them as small in size as possible and I'm also trying to make the script as efficient as possible, hence I wish to avoid excessive linear syntax inside of the strings where it isn't strictly necessary.

What is the correct way to compose a large string with differently styled `"|"` characters? The string have to be as small as possible, with default formatting applied to unstyled characters.

Comment: You're attempt #2 corresponds to `Style[|]` which is not valid syntax. Your attempt #3 with the `|` at the end corresponds to `Style["|"]|` which is again not valid syntax. Can you just use "\"|\"" instead of "|"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The basic issue is that `|` corresponds to an operator, and not a letter. A simpler example:

```
SyntaxQ["a"]
SyntaxQ["|"]
```

> True
>
> False

[`SyntaxQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SyntaxQ) means that the string can be parsed into a Mathematica expression (e.g., [`ToExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression)). You can't expect a string to be syntactically correct when you add an operator in a random place. Can you just use `"\"|\""` instead of "|"?

In order to have [`SyntaxQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SyntaxQ) strings that can be string joined, you probably need to create linear syntax for each string. So, something like:

```
plain = "\!\(\"|\"\)"
bold = "\!\(\*StyleBox[\"\\\"|\\\"\", Bold]\)"
bold <> plain

plain //SyntaxQ
bold //SyntaxQ
bold <> plain //SyntaxQ
```

Here's a pic:

[image]

Comment: I'm trying but it doesn't work: `"\!\(\*StyleBox[\"\\\"|\\\"\",Bold]\)\"\\\"|\\\"\""`. My goal is to get something like "**|** |" as the output (with the ability to `StringJoint` it with similar strings). How can I achieve this?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Could you use a different unicode character? For example, `FromCharacterCode[10072]`?

Comment: I have to use `"|"` because other characters including `FromCharacterCode[10072]` are rendered in a different way. Your updated solution works, thank you.