# How to make the StringExpression not occur in my case?

Tags: string-manipulation

Why is there a `StringExpression` in the following code?

```
f["a b c"] //. x_String :> 
    StringReplace[x, (StartOfString ~~ x1__ ~~ "b" ~~ x2__ ~~ EndOfString) :> f["BBB"]]
(*
    f[StringExpression[f[BBB]]]
*)
```

Though I can remove it, I'd rather it not appear in the first place, because I'm not sure this method is safe:

```
f["a b c"] //. x_String :> 
    StringReplace[x, (StartOfString ~~ x1__ ~~ "b" ~~ x2__ ~~ EndOfString) :> f["BBB"]] /. 
    StringExpression -> Sequence
(*
    f[f[BBB]]
*)
```

Comment: This is clearly covered in the docs for `StringReplace` (point 3 under details): _"If the Subscript[sp, i] in the replacements `Subscript[s, i]->Subscript[sp, i]` do not evaluate to strings, `StringReplace` will yield a `StringExpression` rather than an ordinary string."_

Comment: @rm-rf oh, I see , thanks, `f["a b c b "]//.x_String:>StringReplace[x,Shortest[x1__~~"b"~~x2__]:>f["BBB"]]` this maybe more apparently why need `StringExpression`.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7008/121

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As R.M. described this behavior is [documented](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StringReplace.html):

> If the sp<sub>i</sub> in the replacements s<sub>i</sub> -> sp<sub>i</sub> do not evaluate to strings, StringReplace will yield a StringExpression rather than an ordinary string.

I recommend stripping `StringExpression` as part of the right-hand side of the primary replacement, so that the main expression never has `StringExpression` substituted into it.  A shorter replacement form, e.g. `_[x_] :> x` may be used as the return from `StringReplace` should be either a String or a `StringExpression` object, or you could simply `Apply` `Sequence`:

```
f["a b c"] //. 
 x_String :> 
  Sequence @@ 
   StringReplace[x, (StartOfString ~~ x1__ ~~ "b" ~~ x2__ ~~ EndOfString) :> f["BBB"]]
```

This works because `Sequence @@ "string"` returns `"string"`.