# A problem with set values

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, functions, programming, function-construction

The following code is just an example to clearly explain my problem.

Assume that :

```
In[1]:= Vars = Table[Symbol["x" <> ToString[i]], {i, 1, 4}];

In[2]:= Partition1 = Partition[Vars, 2];
```

Which the Results are :

```
Out[1]:=  {x1, x2, x3, x4}

Out[2]:=  {{x1, x2}, {x3, x4}}
```

Now, I want to do a calculation using above and following codes like below :

```
ExtractionCon = {};

Do[
  Do[

Extraction = Extract[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}}, {i + 1}];

Divided1 = AppendTo[ExtractionCon, Extraction];

, {i, 1, 2}];


SetFunc = MapThread[Set, {Partition1, Divided1}, 2];

, {j, 1, 3}];

SetFunc
```

When I run this code, following error appears :

```
MapThread::mptc: Incompatible dimensions of objects at positions {2, 1} and {2, 2} of
MapThread[Set,{{{3,4},{5,6}},{{3,4},{5,6},{3,4},{5,6}}},2]; dimensions are {2,2} and
{4,2}. >>

MapThread::mptc: Incompatible dimensions of objects at positions {2, 1} and {2, 2} of
MapThread[Set,{{{3,4},{5,6}},{{3,4},{5,6},{3,4},{5,6},{3,4},{5,6}}},2]; dimensions
are {2,2} and {6,2}. >>

Out[5]:= MapThread[Set, {{{3, 4}, {5, 6}}, {{3, 4}, {5, 6}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {3,
4}, {5, 6}}}, 2]
```

Clearly, the problem is `MapThread` ( `SetFunc = MapThread[Set, {Partition1, Divided1}, 2];`). It sets the values `{x1,x2}={3,4} and {x3,x4}={5,6}`. For the first Iteration (`j=1`),it works perfectly, but for more than one Iteration ( `{j,1,3}`), it doesn't. I have already used `Clear[]` or `ClearAll[]`, baut I couldn't fixed it.

How is it possible to unset and reset the values to do the iterations correctly ?

**-EDITED-**

As ***Mr.Wizard*** requested, I put here a better code (I hope!) which unnecessary parts are omitted. I have already add ***Mr.Wizard*** 's suggestions and corrections into the following code. The inputs are :

```
Npop = 2;
NPart = 3;
L = 1;
FEN = 16;
```

Which are `Npop=Number of elements of the Chrom`, `NPart=Number of intervals that I want to have in the outputs`, `L= The unit length that I want to extraxt my intervals from it` and `FEN= The number of whole intervals` .

```
Chrom = {{0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1}};




varsP = Table[Symbol["x" <> ToString[i]], {i, 1, 2 NPart}];

Partitionvars = Partition[varsP, 2];

DivideLenghth = Range[0, L, N[L/FEN]];

ElementPosition = Partition[DivideLenghth, 2, 1];

NumberOfPositionCon = {};
```

`Chrom` is my input with multi-elements (not just one element) for the bellow function:

```
Clear[DoFunction];
DoFunction[Chrom_] :=
Block[{sigma1, Extraction, SplitChrom, NumberOfPosition, 
PositionsOn, ExtractionDL, DivLen, SetEqual, List1},

sigma1 = {};


Do[

ExtractionDLCon = {};


Extraction = Extract[Chrom, {r}];

SplitChrom = Partition[Extraction, Log2[FEN]];

Do[

 NumberOfPosition = FromDigits[SplitChrom[[i]], 2];
 PositionsOn = AppendTo[NumberOfPositionCon, NumberOfPosition];

 ExtractionDL = Extract[ElementPosition, (PositionsOn[[i]] + 1)];

 DivLen = AppendTo[ExtractionDLCon, ExtractionDL];

 Clear["x*"];

 , {i, 1, NPart}];


SetEqual = MapThread[Set, {Partitionvars, DivLen}, 2];

List1 = AppendTo[sigma1, SetEqual];

, {r, 1, Npop}];

List1];
```

When use `DoFunction[]` with input `Chrom`, the result will be :

```
In[1]:=DoFunction[Chrom]

Out[1]:= {{{0.0625, 0.125}, {0.125, 0.1875}, {0.5, 0.5625}}, {{0.0625, 
0.125}, {0.125, 0.1875}, {0.5, 0.5625}}}
```

But the correct answer for `In[1]` must be :

```
The Correct Answer=: {{{0.0625`, 0.125`}, {0.125`, 0.1875`}, {0.5`, 0.5625`}},
{{0.5625`, 0.625`}, {0.625`, 0.6875`}, {0.6875`, 0.75`}}}
```

It seems that `SetEqual` keeps the values and doesn't reset and save new values for next iterations. Could you please help me with this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seem to be at least two issues here:

1. You are not resetting `ExtractionCon = {}` inside the outer `Do` loop, therefore `Divided1` grows longer than `Partition1`
2. With (1) corrected you will get a different error (repeated): `Set::setraw: Cannot assign to raw object 3. >>` because the `x*` Symbols now have values, and they evaluate before the assignment is attempted.

There are likely a number of better ways to write your operation.  For example [Elegant manipulation of the variables list](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/10322/121) may be helpful to you.  If you explain exactly what you are trying to do I shall try to show you how I would write it, and why.

---

Responding to the comment below I am *guessing* that you want something like this, but since I don't know what you are actually trying to accomplish I cannot be certain:

```
Do[
  ExtractionCon = {};
  Do[Extraction = Extract[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}}, {i + 1}];
   Divided1 = AppendTo[ExtractionCon, Extraction];, {i, 1, 2}];
  Clear["x*"];
  SetFunc = MapThread[Set, {Partition1, Divided1}, 2];,
  {j, 1, 3}
];
```

Again I request that you tell me your actual need.  Also please see [Alternatives to procedural loops and iterating over lists in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/121) as you miss out on much of *Mathematica*'s power if you write in explicit loops.

Comment: Could you please elaborate it more ? How it is possible to resetting `ExtractionCon = {}` inside the outer Do loop ?
Without correcting(1), I used `Clear[]` in my loop to clear  `x*` values, but it didn't work. What is wrong with it?

Comment: Thank you Mr.Wizard !! It works perfectly here. I can not believe that how much it was simple and I couldn't do that!

Comment: In fact, this code is just a sample. The original code is something else that I'm trying to write a Fitness Function for a Genetic Algorithm with Mathematica Software. As you know, when the lines of codes grow, the probability of errors will increase. However, I still have problems in the whole code even with the correction of above code. I am trying to find my mistakes or errors.

Comment: I have written a code that when the input is just a single array like `{1,0,0,1}`, it will work perfectly.But when I want to do some iterations and inputs become more than one like `{{1,1,1,},{1,0,0,1}}`, it will face some errors or trap inside a loop! One of that error was a code similar to above code!

Comment: @Shellp Please don't take offense at what I am about to say, because *Mathematica* is really quite unlike most other languages.  You are at a rudimentary stage of *Mathematica* programming, and I am seeking a way to at least illustrate a better style in which to implement your algorithm.  If you are able to give a larger example of what you wish a specific function to accomplish (and the sooner you start thinking in terms of functions the better, re: *Mathematica*), I *shall* try.  For now [this recent post by WReach](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/45958/121) would be a good start.

Comment: Yes, you're right! In fact, I am a beginner and I would be so happy if you could show me a better style in which to implement my codes and algorithm. Thank you so much again.
I will edit this post and add a better example (By considering your corrections in the code).However, I will omit time-consuming and unnecessary parts in the code in order to focus on the problematic part.

Comment: I edited this post and add a better code (I hope!). Thank you so much! :)

Comment: @Shellp I'll try to get around to this in a few hours.

Comment: @Shellp Sorry, I still don't have time to answer this properly.  I've been upgrading the OS on an old machine and its fighting me every step of the way.

Comment: @ Mr.Wizard : Take your time, please !! I'll be waiting for your answer. I have already find an answer and solved my problem. However, I'm sure that you will give an elegant solution for my question. I'm looking forward to hearing from you! :)