# How to export a large number of files?

Tags: export

I have a lot of data sets combined in a big list where each data set comprises one first level sub-list. Each data set must be saved into a separate file. The names for the files must automatically assigned during export.

**How to export different files at the same time?**

The basic form of `Export` is `Export["filename.ext", expr]`, I have not been able to adapt this basic for a sequence of file names, because I don't know how modify the string "filename.ext" to include a sequence number. How could I do that?

I want to generate ten file names using a loop to export the data automatically. I was thinking maybe an expression like

```
Do[Export["filename[[n]].txt", data[[n]]], {n, 1, 10}]
```

where the filename is a list `{name_1, name_2, name_3, .., name_10}`

Comment: `Do[Export["filename" <> ToString[n]<>".txt", data[[n]]], {n, 1, 10}]`

Comment: @rasher Thank you very much for your instant reply! It is very useful!

Comment: Or you can also check the second part of [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/47934/1356).

Comment: You may also want to use `IntegerString` instead of `ToString` to add leading zeros. Check the documentation.

Answer (score 5):

In version 10, you can use [`StringTemplate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringTemplate.html):

```
Export[StringTemplate["filename-`1`.txt"][#], data[[#]]] & /@ Range@10
```

I also like to use [`IntegerString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IntegerString.html) to get numbers with leading zeros. In this case, base 10 and 3 digits.

```
Export[StringTemplate["filename-`1`.txt"]@IntegerString[#, 10, 3], data[[#]]] & /@ Range@10
```

Answer (score 4):

As rasher wrote in a  comment, you need to use some string manipulation in your `Export` expression to generate the file name on the fly.

```
Do[Export["filename" <> ToString[n] <> ".txt", data[[n]]], {n, 1, 10}]
```