# how to change the name of exporting file automatically

Tags: export

I want to export some sort of data from Mathematica to .txt files but every time with a different name.clearly I want the name of files change automatically in each loop for each series of data that are produced in each iteration.

```
s = -1 
While[s < 2*q = 2.;
  \[CapitalDelta] = 0.5;
  smin = -0.3;
  smax = 0.1;
  \[CapitalDelta]s = 0.01;
  L = 5;
  p = 2^L;
  s = s + 0.05;
  H = {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1 - (\[CapitalDelta] + 1)*q, E^s/q, E^s/q}, 
       {0, q E^s, 1 - (\[CapitalDelta] + 1)/q, q E^s}, 
       {0, \[CapitalDelta]*q*E^s, (\[CapitalDelta]*E^s)/q, 1 - (q + 1/q)}};
  IM = IdentityMatrix[2];
  row = ConstantArray[1, p];
  sum = row.H;
  Export["sum,L=5,q=2,d=0.5,s=-1.txt", sum];
  Export["H,L=5,q=2,d=0.5,s=-1.txt", Flatten[H], "Table"]
  ];
```

I want to change "s" in the name of the files each time with the real value of it in that itteration

Comment: You should be more specific (please give some code) but maybe [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48315/how-to-export-a-large-number-of-files) will help.

Comment: Do[Export["superfile-"<>ToString[i]<>".jpg",fig[[i]]],{i,1,10}]

Comment: s = -1
While[s < 2*q = 2.; \[CapitalDelta] = 0.5; smin = -0.3; 
 smax = 0.1; \[CapitalDelta]s = 0.01; L = 5; p = 2^L; s = s + 0.05; 
    H = {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1 - (\[CapitalDelta] + 1)*q, E^s/q, 
    E^s/q}, {0, q*E^s, 1 - (\[CapitalDelta] + 1)/q, 
    q*E^s}, {0, \[CapitalDelta]*q*E^s, (\[CapitalDelta]*E^s)/q, 
    1 - (q + 1/q)}}; IM = IdentityMatrix[2]; 
    row = ConstantArray[1, p]; sum = row . H; 
 Export["sum,L=5,q=2,d=0.5,s=-1.txt", sum]; 
 Export["H,L=5,q=2,d=0.5,s=-1.txt", Flatten[H], "Table"]]

Comment: I want to change "s" in the name of the files each time with the real value of it in that itteration

Comment: @sarakaviani I edited your question to include your code (which I can't get to run as written - the test for the `While` loop isn't constructed right I think).

Comment: Thank you dear Jason.I'm trying to learn Mathematica and am really an amateur!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `"H,L=5,q=2,d=0.5,s=-1.txt"` write for example:

```
"H,L=5,q=2,d=0.5,s="<>ToString[CForm[s]]<>".txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

A very simple solution using TextString and StringJoin:

```
Export[StringJoin["C:\\Users\\...\\first_part_of_name", TextString[variable], ".txt"], sum];
```

Comment: very clean and neat answer, helped me a lot.

Comment: Export[StringJoin["C:/eflut", TextString[A], ".tiff"], out];

I want to label eflut graph of out  with the value of A eg 3,4 but got 2 errors

StringJoin::string: String expected at position 2 in C:/eflut<>TextString[3]<>.tiff. >>

Export::chtype: First argument C:/eflut<>TextString[3]<>.tiff is not a valid file specification. >>

Answer (score 0):

You could generate the filenames using `StringTemplate` with a positional argument:

```
s=-1;
mytemplate := StringTemplate["sum, L=5, q=2, d=0.5, s=`svalue`.txt"]
filestring = mytemplate[<|"svalue" -> ToString[s]|>]
```

(* sum,L=5,q=2,d=0.5,s=-1.txt *)

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way if you are using the `Table[]` function. For example: ``` Table[Export[NotebookDirectory[]<>ToString@StringForm["test``.txt", l], Table[{l,l^2}, {l, 1, 10}]; ```. In this case, the program will generate ten files written as "testl.txt" for each `l` with the values `l` and `l^2` as columns.