# How to visualise Mathematica code and how to become a better coder

Tags: functional-style, education, guidelines

I seem to be using functional coding frequently. However, it does not come naturally and I usually copy from example, and then adapt for my own.   How do you recommend I improve as a coder? I would like coaching on Map, Apply, Thread and others. Is it possible to drill these into the subconscious so the coding starts to free flow.  What functions do I need off pat to become a fully competent coder? What other skills do I need to work on?

Comment: WReach wrote [a good answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/45958/731) on learning Mathematica, I recommend it if you haven't read it before.

Comment: I found [these animations](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/flash/) enlightening, and will sometimes build similar toy examples with symbolic arguments for myself if I need to remember how one of these functions work (I always have to rehash `Outer` e.g.). Which brings up another point, once you've read the docs, and kind of understand build your own examples to test your understanding. If you forget later on, build an example before you go to the docs.

Comment: Thank you both for the interesting links and comments.  I'm reading up now.