# Find and highlight sequence patterns in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, style

Again, I have a list like this:

```
list={0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, \
0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, \
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
```

I want to search for the pattern: **{1,0,0}** and mark all the numbers matching this *sequence* in `Red` with the `Style` option. I tried to use `Cases` to help me out, which does not work. Checked the help a few times, but no idea so far :/

```
Cases[list, {1,0,0}]
```

Comment: Something like : `list //. {b__, PatternSequence[1, 0, 0], a__} -> {b, 
   Sequence @@ (Style[#, Red] & /@ {1, 0, 0}), a}` ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks very nice +1 but i'd put `a___` and `b___` - BlankNullSequence - to include boundary cases for more general situations.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov Thanks Vitaly.

Comment: Thank you! What if I want to change the pattern sequence dynamically e.g. pattern={1,0,0,0};PatternSequence[pattern]. This does not work unfortunately

Comment: @holistic use `PatternSequence @@ pattern` will strip off the `List` head i.e. `{}`, of that pattern and make the pattern the argument of `PatternSequence`. Also, make sure to change the replacement to `(Style[#, Red] & /@ pattern` as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using string manipulations seems to speed things up significantly:

```
randomList = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, 1000];

m1 = randomList //. {b___, PatternSequence[1, 0, 0], a___} -> {b, 
      Sequence @@ (Style[#, Red] & /@ {1, 0, 0}), a} // 
   AbsoluteTiming;

m2 = StringSplit[StringJoin @@ (ToString /@ randomList), 
     "100" -> Sequence @@ (Style[#, Red] & /@ {1, 0, 0})] /. 
    s_String :> Sequence @@ (ToExpression /@ Characters[s]) // 
   AbsoluteTiming;

(* Checking answers from both methods *)
Equal @@ (Rest /@ {m1, m2})
(* True *)

(* Timings *)
First /@ {m1, m2}
(* {0.938379, 0.017024} *)
```

Comment: After having verified your answer I deleted mine. Very very nice!

Comment: Your answer is actually just as fast as mine. The `PatternSequence` in the question's comment is the culprit of the slowness. Hope you could undelete it.

Answer (score 14):

Another functional approach using the Flat attribute:

(Credit to Mr Wizard for the clever form of the second line)

```
SetAttributes[f, Flat];
f[1, 0, 0] = Style[#, Red] & /@ f[1, 0, 0];
List @@ f @@ list
```

Comment: Very nice!  But why so verbose?  `f[1, 0, 0] = Style[#, Red] & /@ f[1, 0, 0];` :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, ooh that's clever! I like it.

Comment: `Flat` has some very interesting effects. I need to learn to use it more, but it is rather counter-intuitive. +1

Answer (score 9):

Using `highlight` from my answer to [Formatting text through pattern matching](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7008/formatting-text-through-pattern-matching/7011#7011):

```
ToString[list] /. highlight["1, 0, 0", Style[#, Red] &]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I keep on thinking how `ListCorrelate` sounds ideal for this but can't find a way. A functional way (but still slower) would be:

```
g[g[b__], d_] := g[b, d];
g[a___, 1, 0, 0] := 
 Sequence[a, Sequence @@ (Style[#, Red] & /@ {1, 0, 0})]
```

and then using `Fold`:

```
List @@ Fold[g, First@list, Rest@list]
```

[image]

**---EDIT---**

which, after Mr Wizard's recommendation, [can be written more compactly](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54784/shorter-syntax-for-fold-and-foldlist) using the two-argument, undocumented form of `Fold` as

```
List @@ Fold[g, list]
```

Answer (score 3):

[image]
[image]

```
list = {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
   0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

SequenceReplace[list, k : {1, 0, 0} :> Splice@(Style[#, Red] & /@ k)]
```

For versions prior to `v12.1`, use `Sequence@@` instead of `Splice`.

```
SequenceReplace[list, 
 k : {1, 0, 0} :> Sequence @@ (Style[#, Red] & /@ k)]
```

[image]

Another variation could be:

```
SequenceReplace[list, k : {1, 0, 0} :> Splice@(Highlighted[#] & /@ k)]
```

[image]

---

Unfortunately, `Sequence*` functions are not as efficient (yet) as some of the other established list manipulation functions. It is a moot point, as this seems to be a visualization task.

Answer (score 2):

A faster variant of **Seismatica**'s answer:

```
List @@ StringReplace[StringJoin[ToString /@ list],
    "100" -> {Style[1, Red], Style[0, Red], Style[0, Red]}] /.
        x_String :> Table[0, {StringLength@x}] // Flatten
```

Here' s a time table running the functions 100 times over a  random 0 | 1 list with 1000 members:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
{a___, $X, b_, c_, d___} /; b == c == 0 ^:= 
  {a, Splice[Style[#, Red] & /@ {1, 0, 0}], d}

list /. 1 -> $X  /. $X -> 1
```

[image]