# Finding the period of an array of integers

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching

A simple array of integers is given. The problem is to detect if a pattern is repeatedly occurring in the array, and find the length of that pattern.

For example, for

```
{19, 6, 19, 6, 19, 6, 19, 6, 19, 6, 19, 6}
```

pattern `{19, 6}` should be detected and its length is `2`.

For

```
{73, 7, 4, 73, 7, 4, 73, 7, 4, 73, 7, 4, 73, 7}
```

pattern `{73, 7, 4}` should be detected and its length is `3`. *(at the end of the array there need not be the complete pattern, but the pattern should start at the beginning of the array)*

For

```
{73, 7, 4, 7, 2, 6, 7, 2, 7, 73, 9, 17, 7, 7}
```

the whole array is the pattern and its length is `14`.

Related links

[MATLAB function seqperiod()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/seqperiod.html#zmw57dd0e102359)

[SO question on cycle detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10441715/finding-a-repeating-sequence-at-the-end-of-a-sequence-of-numbers)

[Related question on this site](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58098/find-patterns-in-a-list?rq=1)

[Wikipedia article on cycle detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection)

Comment: This problem was solved in python pretty cleverly not too long ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29481088/how-can-i-tell-if-a-string-repeats-itself-in-python

I suspect that algorithm is going to be the cleanest and fastest solution in any high-level language that supports finding sequences within a list.

Comment: @QuestionC The answer to that question that compares all other answers is great.

Comment: It's an interesting problem so it drew a lot of attention.  The accepted `(s+s).find(s, 1, -1)` answer is (IMO) pretty amazing, so I wanted to raise attention in case that's applicable in Mathematica.

Comment: For the case of missing or corrupted values, there is some discussion in [this MathGroup thread](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2003/Mar/msg00184.html)

Comment: I wonder if a clever solution based on `Fourier` is possible here? (I'm the guy who came up with the `(s+s).find(s, 1, -1)` solution, btw--flattered to see it's gotten so much attention!)

Comment: How large are the lists you plan to use this on - I think the answers so far can be bettered for large lists, but it that's not the case...

Comment: 5000 elements. @rasher

Comment: @VividD: Ah, then most s/b fine, though *Chris*'s in particular seems quite snappy! Interesting question, +1 on you...

Comment: @QuestionC actually I don't think that algorithm works here, because in this question the cycle does not have to be complete at the end of the list. For example `{1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2}` should display a cycle length of 3, but the concatenate-and-search algorithm would indicate that the string is not periodic.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This uses partitioning, with padding if required, to make sublists.

```
f = Module[{b, c = 1},
    While[Length[b = Union@Partition[#, c, c, {1, 1}, Take[#, c]]] > 1, c++];
    {Length@First@b, First@b}] &;
```

*Example*

```
f@{73, 7, 4, 73, 7, 4, 73, 7, 4, 73, 7, 4, 73, 7}
```

> {3, {73, 7, 4}}

Comment: admire your cleverness, +1

Answer (score 12):

```
ClearAll[len]

len[{p__, p__ .., e___}] /; MatchQ[{p}, {e, __}] := Length[{p}]
len[p_] := Length[p]

len /@ lists
(* {2, 3, 14} *)
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `..` instead of `...`? If `p` has only one partial repeat, above construct doesn't quite get it.

Comment: @kirma Yes, I consciously made it that way because I didn't consider `p` to be a pattern if it never fully repeats itself. For example I thought it best that `{1, 2, 7, 3, 5, 1}` should be counted as one pattern of length six, instead of a pattern of length five. It depends on what the solution is used for I suppose.

Comment: Very nice. +1  .

Comment: @Pickett for my application it is not so critical to make such distinction or not, but I would think your way

Answer (score 11):

I won't bet my hand for this but seems to be ok:

```
ClearAll[return];
return[x : {0 ..., 1}, list_] := {#, list[[;; #]]} &[Length@x];
return[x_, y_] := {Length@y, y};

sqPeriod[list_] := return[FindLinearRecurrence[list], list]



sqPeriod /@ {
   {19, 6, 19, 6, 19, 6, 19, 6, 19, 6, 19, 6},
   {73, 7, 4, 73, 7, 4, 73, 7, 4, 73, 7, 4, 73, 7},
   {73, 7, 4, 7, 2, 6, 7, 2, 7, 73, 9, 17, 7, 7}
   } // Column
```

[image]

Comment: Fails for patterns with length 1: 
`In[1]:= sqPeriod[{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}];
Out[1]= {6, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}}`

Comment: @Gerli Thanks, fixed.

Comment: +1, yours among the ones that seems to get it right, and pretty quickly.

Comment: @rasher Thanks :) I like that MMA lets me skip thinking process sometimes :P

Comment: @Kuba sqPeriod@{73, 7, 4, 73, 7, 4} gives wrong answer, check it out :)

Comment: @matheorem wow, that's unexpected :), any tips?

Answer (score 7):

This answer only returns the period.  If you want to extract the repeating substring, just use `Take[list, period]`.

```
sequencePeriod = Compile[{{l, _Integer, 1}},
  With[{n = Length[l]},
   Catch[
    Do[
     If[
       Catch[
        Do[
         Do[
           If[l[[j]] != l[[k]], Throw[False]];,
           {k, i + j, n, i}
           ];,
         {j, i}
         ];
        Throw[True];
        ],
       Throw[i];
       ];,
     {i, Quotient[n, 2]}
     ];
    Throw[n];
    ]
   ]
  ]
```

For each trial period `i`, I go through the elements `j` of the trial list (`1` through `i`) and make sure that each one is repeated in each subsequent copy of the list (`k`, offset from `j` by multiples of the period `i`).

This is the fastest solution so far:

[image]

I generated the lists for these tests with

```
Join @@ ConstantArray[RandomInteger[n, n], {n}]
```

- Pickett's solution is the most elegant, but seems to have exponential complexity.
- Kuba's has around quartic complexity due to the generality of `FindLinearRecurrence`.
- Chris has cubic performance, since he splits and compares the entire list at each trial period.
- My solution has quadratic performance, since we stop comparison as soon as we encounter a nonmatching element.  It also has low memory usage, since I don't manipulate the array at all.

Comment: Fast is nice, when it's fast and correct. This fails, e.g. `{1,2,3,1,2}` should return 3 per OP, this returns 5.

Comment: @rasher change `Quotient[n,2]` to `n` to get that behavior.

Comment: Please note that in your answer so readers can't miss it, and update benchmark to show the significant performance impact this change has.

Comment: @rasher I would, if not for the comments on Pickett's answer: ["`{1, 2, 7, 3, 5, 1}` should be counted as one pattern of length six, instead of a pattern of length five"](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80163/finding-the-period-of-an-array-of-integers/80253?noredirect=1#comment217293_80168) ["it is not so critical to make such distinction or not, but I would think your way"](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80163/finding-the-period-of-an-array-of-integers/80253?noredirect=1#comment217384_80168)

Comment: @rasher Also, the performance difference is exactly zero for lists that do have a repeat (excepting a difference of one clock cycle for the `/2`/`>>1`), and the difference is around 2x for (random) lists with no repeats.

Comment: Thanks, performance comparison is beautiful, and also valuable info.

Answer (score 7):

In versions 10+, there is  [`FindTransientRepeat`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindTransientRepeat.html):

> - *FindTransientRepeat[list, n] returns a pair of lists {transient,repeat} where the elements of repeat occur successively at least n times at the end of list.*
> - *FindTransientRepeat accepts an incomplete copy of the repeated sublist in the last position*
> - *The minimum number of repetitions refers to complete repetitions*

For the examples in the posted question

```
lists = {{19, 6, 19, 6, 19, 6, 19, 6, 19, 6, 19, 6}, 
         {73, 7, 4, 73, 7, 4, 73, 7, 4, 73, 7, 4, 73, 7},
         {73, 7, 4, 7, 2, 6, 7, 2, 7, 73, 9, 17, 7, 7}};
```

we get

```
FindTransientRepeat[#, 2]& /@ lists
```

> {{{}, {19, 6}},
>     {{}, {73, 7, 4}},
>     {{73, 7, 4, 7, 2, 6, 7, 2, 7, 73, 9, 17}, {7}}}

We can define a function that processes the output of `FindTransientRepeat` to get the results in desired form:

```
Clearall[repeatsF]
repeatsF = Module[{ftr = FindTransientRepeat[#, 2], lst = #},
 If[First @ ftr === {}, {Length @ Last @ ftr, Last @ ftr}, {Length @ lst, lst}]]&;

 repeatsF /@ lists
```

> {{2, {19, 6}},
>      {3, {73, 7, 4}},
>      {14, {73, 7, 4, 7, 2, 6, 7, 2, 7, 73, 9, 17, 7, 7}}}

Answer (score 6):

Using the undocumented `"Periodic"` *padding* as the third argument of `PadRight`:

```
ClearAll[fpF, fpF2]
fpF = Block[{i = 1}, While[i < Length@# && 
      PadRight[#[[;; i]], Length@#, "Periodic"] != #, i++]; i] &;
fpF2 = Block[{i = 1}, While[i < Length@# && 
      PadRight[#[[;; i]], Length@#, "Periodic"] != #, i++]; {i, #[[;; i]]}] &;
```

Examples: Using `tc` from @ubpdqn's answer:

```
tc = {{19, 6, 19, 6, 19, 6, 19, 6, 19, 6, 19, 6}, 
      {73, 7, 4, 73, 7, 4, 73, 7, 4, 73, 7, 4, 73, 7},
      {73, 7, 4, 7, 2, 6, 7, 2, 7, 73, 9, 17, 7, 7}, 
      {6, 3, 6, 3, 3, 6, 3, 6, 3, 3, 6, 3, 6, 3, 3, 6, 3, 6, 3, 3},
      {6, 1, 6, 2, 6, 3, 6, 1, 6, 2, 6, 3, 6, 1, 6, 2},
      {1, 1, 1}, 
      {1, 2, 1, 2, 1}};

fpF /@ tc
(* {2, 3, 14, 5, 6, 1, 2} *)

{#, ## & @@ fpF2@#} & /@ tc // Grid[#, Dividers -> All] & 
(* or {#,fpF @ #, #[[;;fpF @ #]]}&/@tc //Grid *)
```

[image]

If a complete periodic pattern were sought, we could search for periods less than or equal to half the `Length` of the input list:

```
ClearAll[fpFa, fpFb]
fpFa = Block[{i = 1, n = Length@#},  While[i < 1 + n/2 && 
        PadRight[#[[;; i]], n, "Periodic"] != #, i++]; i = If[i < 1 + n/2, i, n]] &;
fpFb = Block[{i = 1, n = Length@#}, While[i < 1 + n/2 && 
        PadRight[#[[;; i]], n, "Periodic"] != #, i++]; i = If[i < 1 + n/2, i, n]; 
        {i, #[[;; i]]}] &;
```

Comment: thank you for introducing me to "Periodic" argument of PadRight :)

Comment: @ubpdqn, just noticed this usage for `PadRight` and `PadLeft` is still undocumented.

Answer (score 6):

[`FindRepeat`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRepeat.html) meets your need perfectly.

```
FindRepeat[{19, 6, 19, 6, 19, 6, 19, 6, 19, 6, 19, 6}]
```

> {19, 6}

```
FindRepeat[{73, 7, 4, 73, 7, 4, 73, 7, 4, 73, 7, 4, 73, 7}]
```

> {73, 7, 4}

```
FindRepeat[{73, 7, 4, 7, 2, 6, 7, 2, 7, 73, 9, 17, 7, 7}]
```

> {73, 7, 4, 7, 2, 6, 7, 2, 7, 73, 9, 17, 7, 7}

Comment: This should be the accepted answer for v11.2+

Answer (score 3):

Late to party, and liking all answers but esp Chris Degnen:

```
per[u_] := Module[{j = 1, lg = Length@u},
  While[Total[
     Abs[Take[Join @@ ConstantArray[u[[;; j]], Ceiling[lg/j]], lg] - 
       u]] != 0, j++]; {j, u[[;; j]]}]
```

Some test cases:

```
tc={{19, 6, 19, 6, 19, 6, 19, 6, 19, 6, 19, 6}, {73, 7, 4, 73, 7, 4, 73, 
  7, 4, 73, 7, 4, 73, 7}, {73, 7, 4, 7, 2, 6, 7, 2, 7, 73, 9, 17, 7, 
  7}, {6, 3, 6, 3, 3, 6, 3, 6, 3, 3, 6, 3, 6, 3, 3, 6, 3, 6, 3, 
  3}, {6, 1, 6, 2, 6, 3, 6, 1, 6, 2, 6, 3, 6, 1, 6, 2}, {1, 1, 1}, {1,
   2, 1, 2, 1}}
```

Testing: `per/@tc`

yields:

```
{{2, {19, 6}}, {3, {73, 7, 4}}, {14, {73, 7, 4, 7, 2, 6, 7, 2, 7, 73, 
   9, 17, 7, 7}}, {5, {6, 3, 6, 3, 3}}, {6, {6, 1, 6, 2, 6, 
   3}}, {1, {1}}, {2, {1, 2}}}
```