# Using lists for creating a bifurcation diagram of an iterative map

Tags: list-manipulation

I'm trying to create a bifurcation diagram of a map I iterate, 
but can't manage to proprely save it as a list within lists and plot it

The code I have is

```
list = RecurrenceTable[{x[n] == r (x[n - 1] - x[n - 1]^3) /. r -> 2.1,
  x[1] == 0.5}, x, {n, 1, 200}]
   newList = DeleteDuplicates[Take[list, -100]];
```

The first list is the iterative map, which I run for 200 times, and the last one is the "final values" of the list.

In the example above I do it for a single value of `r`, however I would like to create lists like `newList` for many different `r` running between 1 to 5, and plot all `newList` I have as a function of `r`

Comment: @AnjanKumar, it's not about creating a module, it's about how to work with lists, also in a module I'll need to do the same thing.

Comment: I think it would be more efficient to add a stop criteria, rather than choosing arbitrarily 200 iterations.

Comment: @jarhead Note that an approach based on `NestList` here is much, much faster than `RecurrenceTable`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's one way, using `Replace` to wrap your points `x` with `{r,x}` and `Table` to iterate over `r`.

```
res = Flatten[Table[
  list = RecurrenceTable[{x[n] == r (x[n - 1] - x[n - 1]^3), x[1] == 0.5}, x, {n, 1, 200}];
  Replace[DeleteDuplicates[Take[list, -100]], x_ -> {r, x}, 1]
 , {r, 1.0, 3.0, 0.01}], 1]

ListPlot[res]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that `r>3.0` doesn't seem to converge, so I stopped there.

Answer (score 8):

Is this what you want?

```
ClearAll[list]
list[r_?NumericQ] :=
  DeleteDuplicates[
    RecurrenceTable[
      {x[n] == r (x[n - 1] - x[n - 1]^3), x[1] == 0.5}, 
      x, {n, 1, 200}
    ][[101 ;; 200]]
  ]
Manipulate[ListPlot[list[r]], {r, 0.01, 5}]
```

[image]

Note that for $r\ge3$, the computation overflows. You may want to decrease the number of iterations or increase the working precision.

If you want to plot *all* points together, as a function of `r` (as in [Chris K](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/6358/chris-k)'s answer), you can also use

```
ListPlot[Table[Sequence @@ Transpose[{r + 0 #, #} &@list[r]], {r, 0.1, 3, .01}]]
```

[image]

Comment: No, here you plot only the last value of the list, I want for every r to have the last 100 points from the iterations without duplicates. I also don't want a smooth plot, but just the points.

Comment: @jarhead I updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I prefer Chris K's answer as it teaches me more on lists manipulation and more useful for further analysis.

Comment: @jarhead You're welcome :-) Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

Your approach has a drawback: it displays the points even if the recurrence relation does not converge to a cycle. The following approach is based on `FindTransientRepeat` (from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/152185/18767)) to detect cycles up to a precision controlled below with `epsi`. You also control the max steps with `nMax`. Another advantage is that it does not compute superfluous points: for instance, with `r = 1.5`, it stops after 4 or 5 iterations instead of 200. Of course, the resulting diagram is not as nice, but the points that are displayed have a meaning (limit cycles).

```
epsi = 10^-3;
nMax = 1000;
searchPeriodicity[r_] := Block[{x = ConstantArray[0, nMax], n},
  x[[1]] = 0.5;
  x[[2]] = r (x[[1]] - x[[1]]^3);
  n = 2;
  While[n < nMax && Last@FindTransientRepeat[x[[;; n]], 2, 
                              SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2] < epsi &)] == {},
   n++; x[[n]] = r (x[[n - 1]] - x[[n - 1]]^3)];
  rep = Last@FindTransientRepeat[x[[;; n]], 2, 
     SameTest -> (Abs[#1 - #2] < epsi &)];
  {r, #} & /@ rep
  ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll look it up, but actually wanted to work my way with my approach, as I wish to represent the points that have not converged to a cycle as well.

Comment: No pb. Just bare in mind that your bifurcation diagram will change arbitrarily if you change 200 to 201 or 199 (which might be questionable). @jarhead *Edit* Well, with your approach you get a plausible envelope, maybe that makes sense too.

Comment: Assuming the transients have died out, the non-periodic orbits probably represent samples of chaotic attractors.