# Highlighting repeated matches with StringCases

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

This is a two-part question:

First, given

```
txt = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
```

Why does this repeated pattern match both instances:

```
txt // StringCases[(t : "the") .. :> t]
```

> {"the", "the"}

Yet this matches only the 2nd instance?

```
txt // StringCases[(pre___ ~~ t : "the" ~~ post___) .. :> 
   Row[{pre, Style[t, Red], post}]]
```

> {"the quick brown fox jumps over (the) lazy dog"}

```
(* note output above uses: pre <> "(" <> t <> ")" <> post  *)
```

Second, provided the first part is solved, what's the best way to output a single string with all instances highlighted, rather than a list of matches?

Comment: I once [asked](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7008) something similar.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

String patterns will always match the longest string possible, since `pre___` and `post___` match anything the second pattern will swallow the whole string. It will not look for further matches inside already matched parts of the string. This is related to the `Overlaps` option, but there is no way to get what we want with `Overlaps` and this pattern.

With `Shortest` we can modify this behavior, perhaps not to achieve what we want though:

```
StringCases[
 txt,
 Shortest[pre___ ~~ t : "the" ~~ post___ ..] :> Row[{pre, Style[t, Red], post}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The best way to achieve highlighting is using `StringReplace` with `StyleBox`:

```
StringReplace[
 txt,
 "the" -> "\*StyleBox[\"the\", FontColor->RGBColor[1, 0, 0]]"
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Example highlighting several different words:

```
StringReplace[
 txt,
 (t : "the" | "jumps") :> "\*StyleBox[\"" <> t <> "\", FontColor->RGBColor[1, 0, 0]]"
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Although I didn't mention it in the Q, I need to be able to match Alternatives, eg ("the" | "jumps")  - hence was gravitating toward `StringCases`. Can you make your without writing a helper function?

Comment: @alancalvitti Yes, see my update.

Comment: I had this as a separate answer but it's just like yours:  `Row@Apply[List]@
  StringReplace[x : "the" | "jumps" :> Highlighted[x]]@txt`, producing [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1I48u.png)

Comment: @JasonB Had never seen `Highlighted` before, so thanks for posting :)

Answer (score 10):

This is just like C.E.'s answer, using `StringReplace`, but with a different highlighting method

```
highlightText[words_List] := ReplaceAll[
   StringReplace[x : (Alternatives @@ words) :> Highlighted[x]]@#,
   StringExpression[a__] :> Row[{a}]] &
```

This will work on strings with and without the keywords but, unlike C.E.'s answer, when the keywords are present your result is not a `String`, but a `Row`.  For display in a notebook, the difference is minimal, but it is worth taking note of.

```
highlightText[{"the", "jumps"}]@"the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
highlightText[{"the", "jumps"}]@"That lazy dog went to sleep"
```

[image]

Comment: Jason, very nice, ready to accept. However, if there's no match, then the output is Row[string]. Can you fix?

Comment: @alancalvitti Ja, but it might be until tomorrow before I can open MMA